# Start a few programs in a split terminal

Tags: macos, gnu-screen, split-window

I want to start a few programs with a single launch script and monitor their outputs to the console.

The easiest way would be to launch in background an xterm for each program, but that's not very neat (I don't like having too many windows around).

The other alternative I've thought of is to redirect their outputs to logfiles and then use `multitail` to watch their outputs in a single terminal, but if I want to kill them I'd need to take a look at their PID's and then issue a `kill` command rather than just going to their terminal and press `Ctrl+C`. Also, this wouldn't work well if some of the program uses curses or similar.

My ideal option would be something like using `screen` to multiplex a terminal (or even show all of them in a split fashion), but I cannot find any option in the manual pages related with that and googling `screen` won't throw any useful result as it is a very generic term.

So, any suggestions on how to achieve something similar to what I want?

Answer (score 1):

No suggestion for your specific problem but have you also considered [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) which is said to be easier to configure.
Have a look at [this](http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/06/28/tmux-the-terminal-multiplexer/) and [this](http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/07/02/tmux-%E2%80%93-the-terminal-multiplexer-part-2/) blog post for more information and some advantages compared to screen.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with screen by loading a custom screen configuration file. Here is an example for starting and monitoring four programs in a split terminal. Create a file `launch_file` somewhere with the following in it:

```
split
split
split
screen program1
focus down
screen program2
focus down
screen program3
focus down
screen program4
```

where program1, program2... are the four programs you wish to run. Now, in a (large) xterm or similar enter `screen -c launch_file`. You should see a four-way split view with one of the programs running in in each. You can use `Ctrl+a tab` to cycle through the four windows, and use `Ctrl+c` to stop one of the programs.